# Blender dosen't use the GPU but the CPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have downloaded Blender, and I have created the donut of Blender guru, but when I started rendering the scene, my GPU doesn't work. I have already selected my GPU in edit/preferences/system/Cycle Render Device:

[image: solution]
[image: solution]

But still, it doesn't work. I have verified that I have downloaded the latest drives. The problem is when I render my model, blender doesn't use my GPU, but it use the CPU, and the rendering is very long.
P.S. I have a Zotac GeForce GTX 1060gb AMP.

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome! What happens *exactly*? What *exactly* does not work? Any error messages? Latest drivers installed? Please take your time and read:   https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the broblem is that when i click F12 to render my model, Blender doesn't use the GPU, but it use the CPU, so the rendering is very long.

Comment: Thanks for adding more information to your question. If the card is enabled in the cuda tab (user prefs) as shown in your screenshot and the device is set to GPU compute it should work, there is no other thing you can click and nothing more to say, unfortunately.  If you are pretty sure about that, consider to report a bug (Help > Report a Bug).

Comment: yes, i'm very sure of that. i have add an image to prove it

Comment: If so, I'd file a bug report (*main menu > help > report a bug*). How to monitor gpu usage: https://www.howtogeek.com/351073/how-to-monitor-gpu-usage-in-the-windows-task-manager/

Comment: I've looked in that site but I dont't understand how it will help me

Comment: If you want to file a bug report: https://developer.blender.org/, you most likely want to show off your gpu usage...

Comment: so, at the moment there isn't any solution?

Comment: The Task Manager doesn't show CUDA usage by default.

Comment: Again, If the card is enabled in the cuda tab (user prefs) as shown in your screenshot and the 'Device' is set to 'GPU compute' there is no reason why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have these values been set in the Render Properties tab?

[image: Render properties tab]

Comment: yes, I have already set that values in the Render Properties tab.